# How to deploy keras-tcn model to vue app with tensorflow.js?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, vuejs3, convolution, text-classification

I make a deep learning model for text classification with keras-tcn layer from [keras-tcn-PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/keras-tcn/). I want to deploy the model to my vue app, but I got this error.

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unknown layer: TCN. This may be due to one of the following reasons:

1. The layer is defined in Python, in which case it needs to be ported to TensorFlow.js or your JavaScript code.
2. The custom layer is defined in JavaScript, but is not registered properly with tf.serialization.registerClass().

I have tried using the GRU model before and it worked. But it doesn't work with this model. How to fix it?